# XML and namespaces using SQL

Tags: sql, xml, xml-namespaces

I have the following XML output from a sql statement

[image: Example XML output]

My sql selection is this

[image: Example SQL selection]

I need the namespaces removed where it appears as `xmlns:udt="3" xmlns:rsm="2" xmlns:ram="1"` so my final output looks like this

[image: Desired XML Output]

Can this be done within the sql selection?

Comment: Please use code, not screenshots. Nobody likes retyping.

Comment: It is a very annoying fact, that any sub-select will insert the namespaces over and over. It was a connect ticket for more then ten years asking the developers to allow more control over the placement of namespace declarations. Connect is dead now and so is the ticket... The only hint is: avoid sub-selects. The only solution is: Use string methods. Another approach is `FOR XML EXPLICIT`, but this is a pain in the neck... And to second Jeroen Mostert: Please do not post pictures...